# Error in Struts2 spring hibernate list display

Tags: json, struts2

I'm just an implementer Struts2 web application hibernate and spring I found a problem when displaying a list with jquery _ json
knowing that I view the model in the console
the exception is:

```
type Rapport d''exception

message org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:102)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:107)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:203)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:177)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:367)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:271)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

Comment: You need the underlying exception (caused by...), because InvocationTargetException is only a layer over the real exception

Comment: how to know the underlying exception???

Comment: look in the server log

Comment: you didn't post `struts.xml` but it seems you have `JSONException`.

Comment: Yes probably if you're using hibernate there's a lazy collection exception underneath this exception. Well the 99% of these exception I've ever seen was thrown by the `JSONWriter` that was trying to parse a `List<Model>` lazy loaded by hibernate -> `LazyCollectionException` -> `JSONException`